# Python 2d array boolean reduction

Tags: python, arrays, reduction

I've got a 2D array comprised of boolean values (True,False).  I'd like to consolidate the array to a 1D based on a logical function of the contents.

e.g. 
**Input:**

```
[[True, True, False],
 [False, False, False],
 [True, True, True]]
```

**Output (logical AND):**

```
[False,
 False,
 True]
```

How would this be done without a loop ?

Comment: Why without a loop? Loops are made to iterate over variable-length iterables, so if you do it without a loop you would lose the "variable-length" benefit (and have to hardcode the indices). Or are you just after an approach that hides the loop from you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to apply logical ANDs to the rows. You can apply `numpy.all`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[True, True, False], [False, False, False], [True, True, True]])
>>> a
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
>>> 
>>> np.all(a, axis=1)
array([False, False,  True])
```

For a solution without `numpy`, you can use `operator.and_` and `functools.reduce`.

```
>>> from operator import and_
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> 
>>> lst = [[True, True, False], [False, False, False], [True, True, True]]
>>> [reduce(and_, sub) for sub in lst]
[False, False, True]
```

edit: actually, `reduce` is a bit redundant in this particular case.

```
>>> [all(sub) for sub in lst]
[False, False, True]
```

does the job just as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Python's built-in `all` method with a list-comprehension:

```
[all(x) for x in my_list]
```

If that's still too loopy for you, combine it with `map`:

```
map(all, my_list)
```

Note that `map` doesn't return a list in Python 3. If you want a list as your result, you can call `list(map(all, my_list))` instead.

Comment: careful with `map` in python 3 though, as it doesn't create a list (but is even better when used within a loop)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without NumPy too. Here is one solution using list comprehension. Explanation: It will loop over sub-lists and even if one of the items in each sub-list is `False`, it outputs `False` else `True`.

```
inp = [[True, True, False],[False, False, False],[True, True, True]]
out = [False if False in i else True for i in inp]
print (out)

# [False, False, True]
```

Alternative (less verbose) as suggested by Jean below:

```
out = [False not in i for i in inp]
```

Comment: This is clever but not exactly equivalent to `x1 and x2 and ... xn` for each sublist when you can have other falsy values in the sublists (such as `0`). Of course, OP explicitly said boolean values, so this is just a sidenote.

Comment: Well the OP said it’s only True or False so my sokution addressed that

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) with the [**`numpy.all`** function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[True, True, False],
... [False, False, False],
... [True, True, True]]
... )
>>> np.all(arr, axis=1)
array([False, False,  True])
```

Here thus the *i*-th element is `True` if *all* elements of the *i*-th row are `True`, and `False` otherwise. Note that the list should be *rectangular* (all sublists should contain the *same* number of booleans).

In "pure" Python, you can use the `all` function as well, like:

```
>>> data = [[True, True, False], [False, False, False], [True, True, True]]
>>> list(map(all, data))
[False, False, True]
```

This approach will work as well if the "matrix" is *not* rectangular. Note that for an *empty* sublist, this will return `True`, since *all* elements in an empty sublist are `True`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

l = [[True, True, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [True, True, True]]

final = list(map(lambda x: reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, x), l))
print(final)
# [False, False, True]
```

The benefit here is that you can change the `reduce` function to something else (say, an OR or something more adventurous).